# 2015 jetta on highway in wrong gear

Tags: vw, jetta, damage

I'm embarrassed to say that I accidentally drove my 2015 Volkswagen Jetta in S gear under the D on my automatic, on the highway.

The car was running smoothly, so I didn't notice until I heard a flapping noise which I assumed was a flat tire.

I stopped, no flat tire, but burning smell. Car has only 700 miles on it. Have I damaged my new car, should I have a mechanic look at it ?

Answer (score 3):

**I doubt you have caused your Jetta any permanent damage**, though the "flapping noise" has me a bit confused. Driving in second gear is not a good thing to do on a regular basis. In most cars, if the engine is being over taxed in a lower driver selected gear, the transmission will force shift into the higher gears to avoid damage. I don't know if VW's are one of those, but would be so considering the German engineering. The burning smell you observed was more than likely paint/oil/protectant being burnt off of the engine (or turbo if it has one). If you continue to hear the "flapping", take it back to the dealership and have them repair it. **DO NOT** tell them how you drove it, just ask them to fix the noise. Even problems caused by driver error are usually covered under warranty, so don't be afraid to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The "flapping" was actually more like thumping. This lead me to believe it was a flat tire, sounded similar, so I pulled off the highway at the nearest rest stop. When I got out of the car, I could smell what seemed like burning rubber.

Comment: @user10172 - Has the flapping/thumping sound continued or has it stopped?

Comment: Hi Paulster  the thumping has stopped, but I have only driven short distances since yesterday . This being a Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

I drive My jetta (2015 S) in sport mode on the freeway (70 mph) if you use cruise control it will shift to 6th gear and without it it'll hold 5th. I have found no immediate damage. S is sport mode, changes the shift points. The smell could be the engine. Mine did it for about 1k miles. The flapping could be minor. Today I found the rubber pice under the front bumper doing this, it came off (not really secure) hope this helps. Best of wishes and enjoy that car! :)